# viewDidDisappear not called when use presentViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, viewwillappear

I have an `UIViewController` having this method:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    NSLog(@"DISAPPEAR");
    lastKnownOrientation = [self interfaceOrientation];
}


-(void)openSendVC{
    SendMsgViewController *vc = [[SendMsgViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SendMsgViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];  
}
```

In the second view controller (`SendMsgViewController`) `viewDidLoad` I have the following:

```
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

where picker is an `UIImageViewPicker`.

The problem is, when I call the method `openSendVC` a new controller is opened, but `viewWillDisappear` (of the first viewController) is not called.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is the correct behavior. Here's an excerpt about `viewWillDisappear:` from the [UIViewController API docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW18):

> This method is called in response to a view being removed from a view hierarchy. This method is called before the view is actually removed and before any animations are configured.

Presenting a new view controller so that it hides the other view controller doesn't count as the view disappearing—only actually being removed from a view hierarchy does (e.g., with something like `popViewControllerAnimated:`).

Comment: But I'm observing that viewDidDisappear is called on the presenting view controller that is presenting a `UIModalPresentationFullScreen` modal, but not with `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` modal.

Comment: @Hlung, you should post this comment as an answer! Thanks!