# iOs Remove Observers from ViewController on TabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a `UITabBarController` with some tab and in all of them i have:

```
-(void)viewDidappear:(BOOL)animated{
   ......
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:kNotificationName object:nil        queue: nil, usingBlock{...}
}
```

and

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
   ......
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

In another class i post the notification with name `kNotificationName`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotification:kNotificationName object:nil];
```

I've set some log on all of this methods, and the order they are called is correct but...if i switch from First to Second tab (and the notification is posted), the first and the second tab receive the notification (but the `viewDidDisappear` of the first tab is called!).

If from second tab i go to third tab, the first, second, and third tab receive the notification.

I've tried to use:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:postNotification:kNotificationName  object:nil];
```

but the behaviour is the same. All observer are notified.

**EDIT1:**
As suggest to the other topic i've moved all in `viewWillAppear:` and `viewWillDisappear:`, but this haven't have any effect.

I've tried to remove the observer after have received the notification, like this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]     addObserverForName:kDLSyncEngineSyncCompletedNotificationName object:nil queue:nil   usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    ....
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:kDLSyncEngineSyncCompletedNotificationName object:nil];
}];
}
```

But, using this (bad) approach too, the notification is received to the first tab too (**i've added this code only on the first tab, to check if after press the second tab, the first tab is receiving again the notification**).

**EDIT2 - SOLVED - (but what is the difference?)**

Instead of using `*addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock*:` I've used `*addObserver:selector:name:object:*` and in this way all works.

Apple documentation say this for the method with usingBlock:

> The block is copied by the notification center and (the copy) held
>   until the observer registration is removed.

Sure, I've called `removeObserver`....

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSNotification is being called multiple times from UITabBarController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029468/nsnotification-is-being-called-multiple-times-from-uitabbarcontroller)

Comment: I've moved all in viewWillAppear: and viewWillDisappear. The chain call is correct (remove observer from the first tab is invoked BEFORE the viewWillAppear: of the second tab), but after notify, the first tab respond to the notify too.

Comment: not clear what you are asking

Comment: If i use addObserver:selector:name:object: and removeObserver it works. If i use addObserverForName:object:queue:usingBlock: and removeObserver dont works. The observer that i have removed continue to handle notification.

Comment: I usually assign an `id` object to the observer. Then I remove it and I nil out it. It works

Answer (score 0):

Inside the block in the addObserver method -

```
usingBlock:^(NSNotification *notification){
                       /*
                       do something
                       */
                       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
                }];
```

As you might have already checked this in documentation -

```
Be sure to invoke removeObserver: or removeObserver:name:object: before notificationObserver or any object specified in addObserver:selector:name:object: is deallocated.
```